# Proving $\sum_{i=0}^{\phi(n)-1} a^i\equiv 0\pmod n$, where $\gcd(a,n)=\gcd(a-1,n)=1 $, from Euler's theorem

Tags: modular-arithmetic, totient-function

> If $\gcd(a,n)=\gcd(a-1,n)=1 $ Then:
> $$\sum_{i=0}^{\phi(n)-1} a^i\equiv 0\pmod n$$

I don’t know how to prove this result, i’ve just made some stuffs :
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\phi(n)}(a^i)-a^{\phi(n)}= \sum_{i=0}^{\phi(n)-1}a^i$$
But i don’t where should i use this.

Comment: Hint: Geometric sum formula

Comment: You mean this $\frac{1-a^\phi(n)}{1-a}$ ??

Comment: Yes, note that this is valid mod $n$ as we assumed $\gcd(a-1,n)=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$(a-1)\sum_{i=0}^{\phi(n)-1}a^i=a^{\phi(n)}-1$$
Since $\gcd(a,n)=1$ we get $a^{\phi(n)}-1\equiv 0\pmod n$. As $\gcd(a-1,n)=1$ we may cancel $a-1$ from both sides: $$(a-1)\sum_{i=0}^{\phi(n)-1}a^i\equiv 0\pmod n\implies\sum_{i=0}^{\phi(n)-1}a^i\equiv0\pmod n$$